# pass a js variable to onkeyup input text

Tags: javascript, html, quotes

Consider the below html code snippet-

I'm trying to pass a js variable pages to `show_data_per_page` function,but I'm getting a syntax error.I also tried the following-

```
<input type='text' name='search' onkeyup='show_data_per_page(pages);'/>
```

or

```
<input type='text' name='search' onkeyup='show_data_per_page("pages");'/>
```

or

```
<input type='text' name='search' onkeyup='show_data_per_page('+pages+');'/>
```

But nothing seems to work.The eclipse editor refuses to recognize `pages` as a js variable.

Please help.

Comment: what exactly is the error?

Comment: multiple annotations found.

Comment: i just need to pass a js variable inside the `show_data_per_page` function.That is my requirement.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? and trying to set `pages` in document ready may be?

Comment: where are you declaring your `pages` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/bNBdX/1/

Working fine for me.

**HTML:-**

```
<input type='text' name='search' onkeyup='show_data_per_page(pages);'/>
```

**JS:-**

```
var pages=10;

function show_data_per_page(obj)
{
    alert(obj);
}
```

Comment: ur code is working fine..But somehow in my code,when i pass just pages to the function inside keyup and i inspect the input element,i can see this `<input type='text' name='search' onkeyup='show_data_per_page(pages);'/>` meaning `pages` was parsed as a string and not as variable.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
This is a part of code to copy from one textbox to another. I tried your requirement of passing a variable to a function via onkeyup. "pages" here will be the variable. Please make changes based on your needs.

**js:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function copy_data(val,pages) {
            var a = document.getElementById(val.id).value+pages
            document.getElementById("copy_to").value = a
        }
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
From:<input type="text" name ="a" id="copy_from" @onkeyup= "copy_data(this,"+pages+")"/><br>
To:<input type="text" name ="b" id="copy_to"/><br>
```